# C++ puro en rutinas de serialización/deserialización

Tags: c++, serialización

Basado en una [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12896824/standard-c-code-for-serialization-deserialization-purposes) del StackOverflow en Inglés.

---

[c](/questions/tagged/c) y [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tienen diferentes modelos de manejo de memoria los cuales en ocasiones se acaban mezclando sin razón aparente; aunque hay ocasiones en que por desconocimiento o por no disponer de otra alternativa, se usa código `C` en programas `C++`.

Por ejemplo, en rutinas de serializacion/deserialización es bastante común usar `memcpy` aunque esta función pertenezca a `C`, y en ocasiones he podido ver usos de `malloc` y `free` pese a que `C++` disponga de `new` y `delete`.

Me gustaría encontrar una alternativa puramente `C++` a las funciones `C` que a veces nos vemos *obligados* a usar en nuestro código:

#### `memcpy` o `std::copy`

[`memcpy`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy) pertenece `C` y se declara en la cabecera [`<string.h>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/). Es una función con importantes agujeros de seguridad pues no hace comprobaciones de desbordado de buffer y elimina toda información de los tipos usados al usar punteros a `void`.

El estándar C11 añadió la función `memcpy_s` que es ligeramente más segura al detectar ciertos errores en tiempo de ejecución como punteros nulos o superposición de buffers, pero sigue sin asegurar la seguridad de tipos al usar punteros a `void`.

Pese a los fallos de seguridad `memcpy` es una opción muy popular dada su flexibilidad de uso:

```
// Enviar datos serializados...
void send(const std::string &value)
{
    const std::string::size_type Size(value.size());
    const std::string::size_type TotalSize(sizeof(Size) + value.size());
    unsigned char *Buffer = new unsigned char[TotalSize];
    unsigned char *Current = Buffer;

    memcpy(Current, &Size, sizeof(Size));
    Current += sizeof(Size);

    memcpy(Current, value.c_str(), Size);

    sendBuffer(Buffer, TotalSize);

    delete []Buffer;
}
```

El código anterior funciona perfectamente, pero no es un código `C++` de calidad:

- Ignoramos la encapsulación de `std::string` al acceder a su memoria interna a través del método `std::string::c_str()`.
- Todo el manejo de memoria se hace manualmente.
- Aritmética de punteros.
- Los datos se tratan como `unsigned char`, ignorando el tipo original.

---

[`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) pertenece a `C++` y se declara en la cabecera [`<algorithm>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm), trabaja con iteradores y sacrifica flexibilidad a cambio de seguridad de tipos, con lo que resulta ser la opción más segura.

La función de enviar datos serializados usando `std::copy` quedaría:

```
// Enviar datos serializados...
void send(const std::string &value)
{
    const std::string::size_type Size(value.size());
    const std::string::size_type TotalSize(sizeof(Size) + value.size());

    std::vector<unsigned char> Buffer(TotalSize, 0);

    std::copy(&Size, &Size + 1, Buffer.begin());
    std::copy(value.begin(), value.end(), Buffer.begin() + sizeof(Size));

    sendBuffer(Buffer.data(), TotalSize);
}
```

Esta versión es más limpia ya que el manejo de memoria deja de ser manual: `std::vector` se encarga de alojar y desalojar la mejoria automáticamente... pero sigue habiendo cosas que no me gustan:

- Las llamadas a `std::copy` mezclan aritmética de punteros y aritmética de iteradores.
- La llamada a `std::vector::data` se salta la encapsulación de `std::vector`.

---

Así que me pregunto:

¿Conocéis alguna aproximación para serializar objetos y valores de manera segura, sin saltarse encapsulación, sin abusar de aritmética de punteros/iteradores y utilizando gestión de memoria automática? Puro `C++`, sin librerías externas.

#### `alloc`/`free` o `new`/`delete` o `std::allocator`

Otro asunto muy importante en la serialización/deserialización es la creación y manejo de bufferes de memoria temporal. [`malloc`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) y [`free`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free) se pueden usar en `C++` (incluyendo la cabecera [`<cstdlib>`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdlib)) aunque pertenezcan a `C`, he visto código haciendo uso de estas funciones en rutinas de serialización porque su formato es muy conveniente para crear bufferes de tamaño determinado, pero `malloc` no garantiza seguridad de tipos (usa punteros a `void`) y la memoria solicitada sólo se [alinea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) con tipos [escalares](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escalar_(inform%C3%A1tica)).

Cualquier puntero es convertible a puntero a `void` sin causar errores o alarmas; esto hace que sea la mejor elección para solicitar memoria genérica para un buffer de serialización, pero `void` no tiene tamaño y por ello no se puede pedir un buffer de `void`:

```
// Pido espacio para 100 void...
void *Buffer = new void[100]; // <-- Error! Que tamanyo tiene 'void'?
```

Dado que `C++` carece de punteros a datos binarios, se usa punteros a `void` para las operaciones de lectura/escritura (por la ausencia de alarmas o errores en la conversión) y punteros a `unsigned char` para crear los bufferes. Se usa `char` para que el número de elementos del buffer coincida con el tamaño y `unsigned` para evitar conversiones inesperadas de signo durante la copia.

Usar este tipo de datos es una práctica común pero sigue sin ser adecuado: `unsigned char` no es `float` ni `mi_fabulosa_estructura_de_serializacion`, así que nos despedimos del tipado fuerte y la seguridad de tipos.

Aparentemente los `allocator` pueden ayudar a reservar memoria con tipado fuerte y alineación correcta de datos pero no se qué diferencia puede haber entre usar `std::allocator<int>::allocate` respecto `new int` o `std::allocator<int>::deallocate` respecto `delete int` así que me pregunto:

¿Cuál serían gestión de memoria dinámica que garantice un tipado y alineado correcto en el contexto de la serialización/deserialización de datos? Quisiera evitar en la medida de lo posible los punteros `unsigned char`.

¿Cuál es el propósito de `std::allocator`? ¿Podría ayudar en el contexto de la serialización/deserialización de datos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando en C++ haces una llamada a `new` implícitamente se acaba llamando a `malloc` ya que es la única forma de solicitar memoria dinámica al sistema (también está `calloc` pero suele llamar internamente a `malloc`). `malloc` forma parte de C++ tanto como `new`. La única diferencia entre ambas es que `malloc` no va a llamar al constructor de la clase, por lo que si creas un objeto con `malloc` el mismo será inestable desde su creación. Por cierto, C++ permite crear objetos en posiciones de memoria a nuestra elección:

```
class Clase
{
  int valor;

public:

  Clase() : valor(5)
  { }

  int Test()
  { return valor; }
};

int main()
{
  // Reserva de memoria con malloc
  Clase* c = (Clase*)malloc(sizeof(Clase));

  // new se encargará de llamar al constructor
  new (c) Clase();

  std::cout << c->Test() << std::endl;

  // Llamada al destructor de la clase
  c->~Clase();

  // Liberamos al memoria reservada con malloc
  free(c);

  // También funciona con posiones en la pila
  char buffer[sizeof(Clase)];
  c = (Clase*)buffer;

  new (c) Clase();

  std::cout << c->Test() << std::endl;
}
```

Para eliminar la aritmética de punteros que comentas en el ejemplo de C++ puedes hacer uso de las funciones de la STL:

```
// Enviar datos serializados...
void send(const std::string &value)
{
    const std::string::size_type Size(value.size());
    const std::string::size_type TotalSize(sizeof(Size) + value.size());

    std::vector<unsigned char> Buffer(TotalSize, 0);

    std::copy(&Size, &Size + 1, Buffer.begin());
    auto itBegin = std::next(Buffer.begin(),sizeof(Size));
    std::copy(value.begin(), value.end(), itBegin);

    sendBuffer(Buffer.data(), TotalSize);
}
```

En cuanto a saltarte la encapsulación... los ficheros y cualquier sistema de transmisión (sockets, bluetooth, etc) manejan bytes. Al final en algún punto tienes que convertir tus datos en bytes y viceversa y las clases en C++ no suelen venir preparadas para obtener una representación binaria de su información interna.

Tampoco hay que olvidar que programar requiere asumir cierta responsabilidad en lo que se está haciendo. Una prueba de ello es que siempre podemos obtener acceso a la información privada de una clase aunque ello implique usar código peligroso. Que se pueda hacer no implica que se deba hacer y para ello un ejemplo:

```
class Test
{
  int variable;

public:
  Test() : variable(1)
  { }

  int Valor() const
  { return variable; }
};

int main()
{
  Test test;

  int* ptr = (int*)&test;
  *ptr = 121;
  std::cout << test.Valor();
}
```

Por este motivo yo no veo peligroso como tal llamar a un método que otorgue acceso directo a la memoria interna de una clase... lo que hay que hacer es ser responsable en esos casos y no usar estas características para hacer sangrar los ojos del siguiente que pase por ese código (al igual que la inmensa mayoría de la gente no utiliza los cuchillos de su cocina para ir rebanando manos).

Otra alternativa quizás más saludable para nuestro código pasa por dejar que una librería serialice el código por nosotros.

- Puedes usar Qt, que dispone de metadatos que permiten realizar una serialización de tus objetos de forma rápida y sencilla. La pega es que te toca cargar con Qt y sus metadatos.
- Hay librerías de serialización que te ofrecen una intertaz más o menos elegante. Te despreocupas de la gestión de la memoria pero pierdes el control sobre cómo se realiza la serialización (aunque esto no siempre debería ser un problema). Lo más tedioso suele ser configurar la librería para que sepa serializar nuestras clases (si modificamos la interfaz pública de la clase hay que modificar la configuración de la serialización).

Lo que no se debería perder de vista es que a la hora de serializar información para transmitirla a otro dispositivo hay que tener especial cuidado en el protocolo de transmisión. Si los datos se envían en binario es facil acabar teniendo incompatibilidades por el alineamiento de los bits (por ejemplo big endian vs little endian). Lo más recomendable en este caso es introducir un mecanismo de serialización que sea independiente de la arquitectura del sistema (Json, XML, XDR, ...).

Un saludo.

Comment: Ya conocía el [placement new](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) mas no creía que pudiera ser de ayuda en esta situación; lo estudiaré con más detalle. Respecto a *Cuando en C++ haces una llamada a `new` implícitamente se acaba llamando a `malloc`* no encuentro **nada** [en el estándar](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) que lo indique; así que asumo que es un detalle de implementación del compilador. (dirígete a 3.7.4.1 Allocation functions).

Comment: He encontrado una referencia a `malloc` en la sección que mencionaba: *The intent is to have `operator new()` implementable by calling `std::malloc()` or `std::calloc()`, so the rules are substantially
the same. C++ differs from C in requiring a zero request to return a non-null pointer.* Así que la llamada a `malloc` o `calloc` es efectivamente un detalle de implementación más no obligatorio.

Comment: Claro, no es obligatorio. De hecho tu puedes sobreescribir `new` para gestionar las reservas de memoria (por ejemplo para reservar la memoria por bloques, de forma que solo algunos `new` conlleven una reserva de memoria). El caso es que en C++ la única forma de solicitar memoria al sistema operativo es con `malloc`. Siempre puedes implementar una función propia que hable con el SO, pero la solución posiblemente no sea portable.

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que no planteas una pregunta simple, sino más bien varias, y veo también que en los considerandos hay algunas afirmaciones que estás dando por ciertas, que creo que no lo son tanto, o nada. Por ejemplo:

> ... en rutinas de serializacion/deserialización es bastante común usar
>   memcpy aunque esta función pertenezca a C...

std::memcpy es una función de la biblioteca estándar C++ (en cstring), y en principio no creo que tenga nada de criticable, de hecho muchas librerías (y compiladores) la usan asiduamente. Posiblemente haya un número de malos usos y consecuencias lamentables, pero eso en todo caso vale como advertencia sobre los usuarios descuidados más que sobre la función. Dada la alternativa de usar std::memcpy() o std::copy, debería entrar en consideración que la primera es más eficiente que la segunda, y si se está escribiendo una librería, esa sería una buena razón para darle crédito. Y discúlpame que insista, pero si tu primera premisa era que una es del lenguaje C y la otra del C++, esa premisa es falsa, y cualquier cosa que se derive de ella convendría replantársela.

> El código anterior funciona perfectamente, pero no es un código C++ de
>   calidad

No lo es, pero me parece que no tanto por el estilo sino por lo que hace (o deja de hacer). No tiene en cuenta las posibles diferencias de endianness, o que `sizeof(std::string::size_type)` depende del modelo de datos implementado por el sistema.

Haciendo abstracción de los motivos, y con respecto a

> ¿Conocéis alguna aproximación para serializar objetos ...?

Por ejemplo, existe hace varios años y es muy usada la [boost serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html), aunque la parte de

> ... puro C++ sin librerías externas...

adolece en mi opinión del un defecto similar al anterior (en este caso sería una *contradictio in terminis*); si hay algo que caracteriza a las librerías boost es su reputación de "puro C++", y como además son open-source, al copiar y pegar su código, ¿dejaría de ser una "librería externa"?

> Usar este tipo de datos es una práctica común pero sigue sin ser
>   adecuado: unsigned char no es float ni
>   mi_fabulosa_estructura_de_serializacion, así que nos despedimos del
>   tipado fuerte y la seguridad de tipos.

Pero, ¿cuál es la idea de "serializar" si no convertir un float o lo que sea a una secuencia de unsigned char? ¿En qué sentido encuentras que el lenguaje ha perdido su condición de strongly-typed? Traducir 2 como "dos",  ¿provocaría la misma pérdida?